# Formatted input from string in c++

Tags: c++, scanf, formatted

I am making a statistics collector that reads the log of a music player and lets the user show top ten most played etc. As a noob project.

A line from the log looks like: "20:42:03   start   E:\ROTATION\A\Håkan Lidbo - Dammlunga.mp3"

I have put this in a string using ifstream and getline.

Then making an array of chars of the string using

```
const char *charveqtur = newline.c_str();
```

Then I tried to sort i out with sscanf:

```
sscanf (charveqtur, "%d:%d:%d\tstart\t%s", &this->hour, &this->minute, &this->second, &this->filename);
```

The problem is that the filename is cut at the first space. I have also tried using istringstream instead but no breakthrough so far.

Which is the most convinient way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Read character per character after the "start ", till you reach a \n char ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use some input stream to read the first integers and colons, and because the filename is the last entity, you can then use `std::getline`. However, even if your filename is not the last part, note that `std::getline` is quite a versatile function that accepts any delimiter.

A more advanced method would be to define your own type for filenames and overload `operator>>(std::istream &, T const &)` on it.

Here is a complete example using `std::getline` and `stringstream` with basic diagnostics and some reformatting:

```
#include <sstream>  // for istringstream
#include <iostream> // for cout and cerr
#include <iomanip>  // for setprecision
#include <cmath> 

bool read (std::string const &line) {
    char c = 0;
    double length;
    double rating;
    std::string title;

    std::istringstream ss;
    ss.str (line);
    ss >> length;        
    if (!ss.good())    { std::cerr << "invalid length\n"; return false; }
    if (ss.get()!=':') { std::cerr << "expected colon\n"; return false; }
    ss >> rating;
    if (!ss.good())    { std::cerr << "invalid rating\n"; return false; }
    if (ss.get()!=':') { std::cerr << "expected colon\n"; return false; }
    std::getline (ss, title);


    double sink;
    std::cout << title << " (" 
              << int(length) << ':' << 60*std::modf (length,&sink)
              << " min), your rating: " << rating << '\n';

    return true;
}

int main () {
    read ("30.25:5:Vivaldi - The four seasons.ogg");
    read ("3.5:5:Cannibal Corpse - Evisceration Plague.ogg");
    read ("meh");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Vivaldi - The four seasons.ogg (30:15 min), your rating: 5
Cannibal Corpse - Evisceration Plague.ogg (3:30 min), your rating: 5
invalid length
```

**Important**: When parsing, you are sailing close to the security risks. Always be conscious and sensible and try to use tested and proven libraries where possible. This also implies that you *do not use `sscanf`, which is **not typesafe**, **error-prone** and sometimes **hard to get right***.

Don't use C if you have C++, and used correctly, iostreams are even more convenient than printf/scanf+co.

Comment: Hoho it was a lecturer at uni who told me to use scanf! Thanks for the code

Comment: I tend to not trust unis and schools when it comes to clean coding.They often even tend to teach non-portable code or C++ code that `exit()`s from deep in the call tree (hint: it circumvents all the RAII philosophy, which teachers are often not aware of, too) /rant

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps do something like

```
int lastpos = 0;
if sscanf (charveqtur, "%d:%d:%d\tstart\t%n", &this->hour, 
           &this->minute, &this->second,
           &lastpos) > 3 && lastpos >0) {
    std::string filename = newline.substr(lastpos);
    /* do something with filename */
}
```